# Add a new element exactly after the existing same one

Tags: linux, bash, xmlstarlet

I am trying to modify the [server.xml](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/conf/server.xml) file of the `Apache Tomcat`.
I would like to add a new element exactly after the last `Connector` definition but my solution adds the new content at the end of the `Service`, not after the last  `Connector`.

**This is my XML:**

(I removed the irrelevant attributes and elements from the real XML to make it more readable)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.aaa"/>
    <Listener className="org.bbb" SSLEngine="on"/>
    <GlobalNamingResources>
        <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"/>
    </GlobalNamingResources>
    <Service name="Catalina">

        <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"/> 
        <!-- INSERT A NEW CONNECTOR HERE -->

        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Realm className="aa">...</Realm>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

My `xmlstarlet` code inserts the desired content, but the position of the new `Connector` element is wrong.

**xmlstarlet:**

```
xmlstarlet edit \
    -s "//Server/Service[last()]" -t elem -n "Connector" \
    -s "//Server/Service[last()]/Connector" -t attr -n port -v "443" \
    -s "//Server/Service/Connector[@port='443']" -t attr -n protocol -v "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" \
    1.xml
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.aaa"/>
  <Listener className="org.bbb" SSLEngine="on"/>
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"/>
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="aa">...</Realm>
    </Engine>

    <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"/>

  </Service>
</Server>
```

But I want to have the new `Connector` after the existing one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.aaa"/>
  <Listener className="org.bbb" SSLEngine="on"/>
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"/>

    <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"/>

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="aa">...</Realm>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

What I missed in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
xmlstarlet edit\
--append  /Server/Service/Connector    --type elem -n "Connector" \
--insert '/Server/Service//Connector[last()]' -t attr -n "port" -v "443" \
--insert '/Server/Service//Connector[last()]' -t attr -n "protocol" -v "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" \
1.xml
```

Comment: Why should he try that? What does that do? [answer]

Answer (score 0):

With `xmlstarlet edit` option `-s` adds a node as last child,
`-i` as preceding sibling, and `-a` as following sibling, to each
member of their XPath argument.
With `-t attr` they all add an attribute and have no influence on
attribute order.

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
  -a '/Server/Service[@name="Catalina"]/Connector[last()]' -t elem -n 'Connector' \
  --var T '$prev' \
  -s '$T' -t attr -n port -v '443' \
  -s '$T' -t attr -n protocol -v 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol' \
file.xml
```

`--var` defines a named variable, and the back reference `$prev`
variable (aka `$xstar:prev`) refers to the node(s) created by the most
recent `-s`, `-i`, or `-a` option which all define or redefine it
(see [`xmlstarlet.txt`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet.txt)
for examples of `--var` and `$prev`).